# change length of string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem I want to change the length of string. This is my string of characters that I want to change.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim .

I use `substring` function in javascript but the outputs is not like I need.
this is my code

```
var str="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ";
document.write(str.substring(100)+"<br />");
```

but the output is like this

```
laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim
```

My goal is just to make the length of that string of character to be  100 starting from the first character.

how i can solve this...thanks for your answer

Comment: how do you want to change it's length? by predetermined character length? by finding a certain word and clip it there?

Comment: does anyone use `document.write` anymore? The answer to your question is already in my answer. `str.substring(0, 100)`.

Comment: document.write just to view my result. okay i fix this with your code.thanks you @mrtsherman.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears english is a second language for you and your question is very unclear. But based on what you posted I am guessing you want to truncate a string. This is straightforward using javascript's string methods.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html

```
//example of truncating a string based on # of characters
var foo = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim."
var bar = foo.substring(0, 100);

//if you want to truncate at a particular word then use indexOf to find it in orig string
var banana = foo.substring(0, foo.indexOf('tincidunt'));
```

Comment: Better more concise answer than mine